# Is there anyway to scrap a website which holds 15000 hrefs in puppeteer

Tags: dynamic, puppeteer

I am new to Puppeteer, Is there anyway to scrap a website which holds 15000 hrefs in puppeteer and loads dynamically?

I have used some sample codes shared by you all and could do some basic scraping. But output file shows only up to some 100 hrefs. There are mroe than 15000 hrefs loaded in my website.

The website is designed in such a way that the next page button loads the items in same page. So when the page is 140, it would contain 15000 items and links to it. How do I achieve to scrap all hrefs in Puppeteer ?

Thanks for all your help friends.

I have used some sample codes shared by you all and could do some basic scraping. But output file shows only up to some 100 hrefs.

`....

```
 await page.goto(URL, {timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
//working for hrefs
    let hrefs = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let Element = Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('a'), (el) => el.href);
      return Element;
  });
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a way, but it's only possible to say what that might be by looking at the website. Please provide it to receive help. Thanks. In the meantime, try clicking those buttons you mentioned and [avoid using timeout: 0](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#using-infinite-timeouts), and probably also [using `domcontentloaded`](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded). Your code can be shortened: `await page.$$eval("a", els => els.map(el => el.href))`.

Comment: Is it this kind of website that require to scroll down to load more items? If yes, use  JS to scroll down